# Suppressing Static Code Analysis Warning CA1806 for TryParse calls

Tags: c#, coding-style, fxcop

I was wondering what people's thoughts were on the [CA1806 (DoNotIgnoreMethodResults)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182273.aspx)  Static Code Analysis warning when using FxCop.

I have several cases where I use Int32.TryParse to pull in internal configuration information that was saved in a file.  I end up with a lot of code that looks like:

```
Int32.TryParse(someString, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out intResult);
```

MSDN says the default result of intResult is zero if something fails, which is exactly what I want.

Unfortunately, this code will trigger CA1806 when performing static code analysis.  It seems like a lot of redundant/useless code to fix the errors with something like the following:

```
bool success = Int32.TryParse(someString, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out intResult);
if (!success)
{
 intResult= 0;
}
```

Should I suppress this message or bite the bullet and add all this redundant error checking?  Or maybe someone has a better idea for handling a case like this?

Thanks!

Comment: This title is inappropriate, please use something akin to : "When is it okay to swallow Style warnings?" and re-phrase the question appropriately. As it stands, this is in danger of being closed "Not a Question"

Answer (score 8):

Why not refactor your `TryParse`s into a single function with the behavior you're after?:

```
static int ParseOrDefault(string someStr)
{
    int result = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(someStr, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That way you avoid the annoying warning and ditch the redundant code. A separate function makes your expectations explicit and leaves no room for confusion.

Comment: Why do you have multiple returns?  that is a very bad practice that leads to awkward testing and refactoring.

Comment: @Firoso - this would work as a string extension method as well (named differently). Multiple returns don't trouble me, especially in a short function. Bruce Eckel doesn't seem to mind them either: http://onthethought.blogspot.com/2004/12/multiple-return-statements.html. But by all means avoid them if you dislike them.

Answer (score 4):

Bite the bullet, or at least add comments.  How does Johnny the Homicidal coder know that Int32.TryParse will provide a 0 output without looking at external documentation?  Similarly, how does he know that 0 is what you WANT the default to be?  The later implementation is specific in its purpose, so I have to agree with FxCop here.

Remember, Johnny knows where you live.

With that being said, I OFTEN suppress style cop, (largely because I use the async CTP which doesn't play nice together yet).  Style guidelines are just that, guidelines.  Use your head, but always err on the side of clarity if performance is a non-issue.

Keep in mind that behavior like this could be changed in the future, do you always want to have 0 to be the default? Could this change?  Even if you refactor into a ParseOrDefault helper method, you should probably account for reasonable change of defaults during product lifetime.

Comment: If Johnny knows his C# he will know this because the called method is *required* to assign a value to any parameter declared using the `out` modifier. This is nothing that is special about `Int32.TryParse`.

Comment: Except that the Int32.TryParse assignment to 0 is still specific (although common) to that method, plus, who said Johnny is competant? ;-)  He's just homicidal.

Comment: true, that the value is `0` is specific to `TryParse`. And homicidal is a rather strong argument :o)

Answer (score 1):

Suppress away!

FxCop/Code Analysis is only really guidelines. It can help improve parts of your code, especially if it's being distributed to other developers for use, but at the end of the day, it's only a guideline and you can code however you like.